# In a clairvoyance test, a stack of 25 cards with 5 types is used. You take 3 cards at once. In how many ways can you not take cards of type 1 and 2?

Tags: combinatorics

In a clairvoyance test, a stack of 25 cards is used, with each of the 5 types of cards occurring 5 times.

You take 3 cards at once. In how many ways can you not take cards of type 1 and type 2?

Solution:

There is no difference between cards of the same type.
The possible cards that you can take are:

type 3 - type 3 - type 3

type 4 - type 4 - type 4

type 5 - type 5 - type 5

type 3 - type 3 - type 4

type 3 - type 3 - type 5

type 4 - type 4 - type 3

type 4 - type 4 - type 5

type 5 - type 5 - type 3

type 5 - type 5 - type 4

type 3 - type 4 - type 5

I think there are 10 possibilities. However, my book provides ncr (15,3) as a solution. What is correct?

Comment: Your book is considering there to be a difference between cards of the same type, where as you are not, hence the difference in your answers.

Comment: What about the comment of @quasi? I think it is wrong...

Comment: quasi is assuming the cards within a type are distinct, and is correct under that assumption.

Comment: Indeed, but that is just what you said. Isn't it? My answer is correct in case that we do not district cards of the same type?

Comment: This is why it is better to ask these sorts of problems about probabilities, which are unambiguous, rather than (only) enumeration. The only advantage (but it is huge) of treating the cards as distinct is that the outcomes are equally likely which makes the probability computation simple. The text books should be more careful about these sorts of ambiguities in the wording of pure enumeration questions, since the "equally likely" aspect is of no relevance if you aren't computing probabilities.

Comment: @Ned what do you mean with “since the equally likely aspect is of no relevance if you aren’t computing probabilities”?

Comment: What does "ncr(15,3)" mean.

Comment: " My answer is correct in case that we do not district cards of the same type?"  Yes, but why would you not distiguish between cards of the same type?  The jack of diamonds is a completely different card than the three of diamonds.

Comment: I mean the OP's interpretation is a perfectly valid combinatorial problem -- the number of distinguishable unordered hands where the the multiple cards of each type are taken to be indistinguishable. Now it's kind of silly to be asking for that when you give the additional info of "5 cards of each type" which in math-text-book-talk surely is implying that you should treat the cards as distinguishable. But that's why I think it is better to ask for the probability since then there is no ambiguity .... beginners may not be familiar with the linguistic conventions of math problem sets.

Answer (score 1):

The book is correct.

To see where you went wrong, consider the following outcomes . . .

The number of ways to get three $3$'s is ${\large{\binom{5}{3}}}=10$.

The number of ways to get two $3$'s and one $4$ is 
${\large{\binom{5}{2}}}{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}=50$.

The number of ways to get one $3$, one $4$, and one $5$ is
${\large{\binom{5}{1}}}^3=125$.

So these three outcomes are not equally numerous as $3$-card hands, but in your analysis, you gave them the same weight.

The key is that the $25$ cards cards are physically distinct, so two distinct cards of the same rank should not be regarded as the same card.

Thus, since there are $15$ cards with ranks $3$, $4$, or $5$, the number of $3$-card hands from those $15$ cards is ${\large{\binom{15}{3}}}$.

Comment: Bu the number of ways to get three 3's is just 1? There is no difference between cards...

Comment: Number the cards from $1$ to $25$ using invisible ink. Now they are all different, even if the test taker can't see the difference. Alternatively, consider the position of a card in the deck, A card with rank $3$ at positiion $1$ is not the same card as a card of rank $3$ at position $8$, say.

Comment: The book is clearly regarding physically distinct cards as distinct (which is the natural interpretation, unless specified otherwise).

Comment: Also note: The context is a "clairvoyance test", so a blind guess of $3,4,5$ should not be credited the same as a blind guess of $3,3,3$, since the outcome $3,4,5$ is $12.5$ times more likely to occur than the outcome $3,3,3$.